# How to access local files from AzureML File Share?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Earlier when using AzureML from the Notebooks blade of Azure ML UI, we could access the local files in AzureML using simple relative paths:

[image]

For example, in the above image to access the CSV from the `test.ipynb` we could just mention the relative path:

```py
df = pandas.read_csv('WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv')
```

However, we are not able to do that anymore.

Also when we run

```py
import os
os.getcwd()
```

We see the output as
`'/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/<cluster-name>'`.

Hence, we are unable to access the files in the FileStore which was not the case earlier.

When we run the same from the JuyterLab environment of the compute environment we get:

`'/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/<cluster-name>/code/Users/<current-user-name>/temp'`.

We can easily solve it by adding the path `'/code/Users/<current-user-name>/temp'` at the base and use that instead. But this is not recommended as with a change in the environment we are using the code needs to change every time. How do we resolve this issue without going through this path appending method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the Notebooks team in AzureML, I just tried this. Did this just start happening today?

It seems like things are working as expected: [image]

Comment: I do think it was a change that happened yesterday (when I posted). It was working as expected for me too till yesterday.

Comment: I believe this issue was temporary and was fixed after you comment.